# Makefile run more than once

Tags: java, makefile

I'm trying to compile my Java code with this Makefile. How ever when I run make, it compiles the code more than once.

Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all clean run

SOURCES = \
    Models/CustomException \
    Models/Forest \
    Models/ForestContainer \
    Models/Owner \
    Models/OwnerContainer \
    Models/Tree


SRC = $(addprefix src/, $(addsuffix .java, $(SOURCES)))
BIN = $(addprefix bin/, $(addsuffix .class, $(SOURCES)))

all: ${BIN}

clean:
    -rm -f ${BIN};

${BIN}: ${SRC}
    mkdir -p bin/Controllers;
    mkdir -p bin/Models;
    mkdir -p bin/Views;
    javac -d bin ${SRC};

run: all
    java -cp bin Program;
```

Output:

```
┌─( klim ) - ( ~/workspace/Forest-mvc )
└─> make

mkdir -p bin/Controllers;
mkdir -p bin/Models;
mkdir -p bin/Views;
javac -d bin src/Models/CustomException.java src/Models/Forest.java src/Models/ForestContainer.java src/Models/Owner.java src/Models/OwnerContainer.java src/Models/Tree.java;
mkdir -p bin/Controllers;
mkdir -p bin/Models;
mkdir -p bin/Views;
javac -d bin src/Models/CustomException.java src/Models/Forest.java src/Models/ForestContainer.java src/Models/Owner.java src/Models/OwnerContainer.java src/Models/Tree.java;
mkdir -p bin/Controllers;
mkdir -p bin/Models;
mkdir -p bin/Views;
javac -d bin src/Models/CustomException.java src/Models/Forest.java src/Models/ForestContainer.java src/Models/Owner.java src/Models/OwnerContainer.java src/Models/Tree.java;
mkdir -p bin/Controllers;
mkdir -p bin/Models;
mkdir -p bin/Views;
javac -d bin src/Models/CustomException.java src/Models/Forest.java src/Models/ForestContainer.java src/Models/Owner.java src/Models/OwnerContainer.java src/Models/Tree.java;
mkdir -p bin/Controllers;
mkdir -p bin/Models;
mkdir -p bin/Views;
javac -d bin src/Models/CustomException.java src/Models/Forest.java src/Models/ForestContainer.java src/Models/Owner.java src/Models/OwnerContainer.java src/Models/Tree.java;
mkdir -p bin/Controllers;
mkdir -p bin/Models;
mkdir -p bin/Views;
javac -d bin src/Models/CustomException.java src/Models/Forest.java src/Models/ForestContainer.java src/Models/Owner.java src/Models/OwnerContainer.java src/Models/Tree.java;
```

As you can see it runs the commands more than once, actually 6 times. The number of times it run the commands increase/decrease as number of SOURCES are added/removed

How can this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add the main classes after javac.

```
${BIN}: ${SRC}
    javac -d bin -cp . Models/Tree.java
```

All the classes and the folders (packages) that depend of the main classes will be automatically compiled. Your make is compiling again and again some classes that have already been  compiled.

Answer (score 0):

The first target in your `Makefile`, `all`, depends on 6 different sub-targets. Presumably, at the beginning of the run, none of these exists, so `make` thinks it needs to build each of those 6 sub-targets. However, building any one of those sub-targets actually builds all 6 of them the way you have this defined - but `make` doesn't know that.

The bottom line is, it's doing what you told it to. The fact that what you told it to do is redundant doesn't matter to `make`.

Answer (score 0):

For each target int ${BIN} make will invoke the ${BIN}: ${SRC} rule but you give it all the sources on the command line for javac.  You probably want to replace the ${SRC} with $< on the javac line.